# Display simple product SKU on config product pages after attribute selection

Tags: magento2.2.3

I am looking to have the configurable SKU change to the corresponding simple product SKU when the configurable product attributes have been selected. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you using only one configurable attribute or multiple mean size or size and color?

Comment: I am using muliple

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change, but **not SKU**.

More information about which elements on the page change when options are selected can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to display product SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing SKU for each simple product.

Switching SKU added in `getJsonConfig()` when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.